# Changing webkit transtion speed during transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I need to smoothly scroll a large amount of text up the screen.  Using webkitTransform does this very well, but I would also like to enable the user to change the speed of the scrolling or pause the scrolling based on how fast they're reading.  From what I've found, there isn't a way to change the duration of a webkit transition once it has started. Using setInterval and moving the text works, but it gets jumpy and hard to read as the speed increases.

Can anyone recommend a good way to do this that would allow for the user to adjust speed and still give readable text at higher speeds?

Comment: Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about modifying currently running CSS3 transformations, but as an alternative solution, I would scroll a large amount of text with JavaScript by using the browser's native scrolling with [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) ([.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) if you are using jQuery). 
This allows the user to have a familiar interface even without JavaScript, and can be simply implemented with [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) or [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).  If the final result is too jumpy, try modifying `scrollTop` in smaller intervals, but faster.  (i.e., instead of adding +100 every 500ms, try adding +10 every 50ms)